# Is set x+y where x$\in G_1$ and $y \in G_2$ open or closed or neither( Description of open and closed sets)

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

The following question was part of topology quiz and I was unable to think on how should I approach this question. A similar question was also asked in another quiz and I could also not answer it.

> Let $G_1 $ and $G_2$ be two subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a function. Then if $G_1$ is open and $G_2$ is closed then $G_1 +G_2$ ={x+y : $x\in G_1$ , $y\in G_2$} is neither open nor closed.

The problem is i am unable to see how $G_1 +G_2$ looks like( I mean how to write an open set and closed set in it) . What does + means to elements of set $G_1 $ and $G_2$?

That's why I could not solve this problem and require your help.

Comment: $+$ in $\Bbb R^2$ could mean component-wise addition

Comment: What is $f$ good for? Also, the statement is wrong in general. Choose $G_1=\mathbb R ^2=G_2$.

Comment: Was it a true/false question?

Comment: @Zuy I am only asking for a part of whole uestion . f was used somewhere else in same question.

Comment: @AnikBhowmick yes it was true /false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $y \in G_2$. Then since $G_1$ is an open set, we have $G_1 +y = \{x + y : x \in G_1 \}$ is an open set too. Now take union over $y \in G_2$. What can you say from here?

> In my opinion, $G_1$ $+$ $G_2$ should be an open set